# Python 3: "next" attribute in str_iterator object

Tags: python, string, iterator, iteration

(not sure if telling the Python version is helpful so i will just leave that in the title)

hi again im asking a thing about the "next()" function.

this code is about checking whether your input contains "o" or "re":

```
input = input("Your Oreo set: ").lower()
oreo = iter(input)
print(input)

res = """wait. something wrong has happened...
did you even enter anything lolz"""

for ch in oreo:

    if (ch == "o") or ((ch == "r") and (ch.next() == "e")):
        res = "hi, the oreo is being made..."

    else:
        res = "hi, this is not an oreo pattern. you can only enter either \'o\' or \'re\' to make one."
```

i used the next() function so that i can check if the input has "re" that has two characters in it

but i keep getting the AttrbueError saying that the string object does not have a "next()" method. 
i thought i can the iter() function to allow the input be an iterable??

so here is the question i get: 
how can i allow the input (aka the "oreo" variable) to use the next() method??

Comment: `and (ch.next() == "e"))`? Are you trying to check the next value?

Comment: @roganjosh yeah

Comment: The code doesn't make any sense to me. `oreo = iter(input)` you want it to iterate through every character individually?

Comment: @roganjosh you're right

Comment: The way to get the next value from an iterator is `next(it)`, but `ch` is not an iterator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to iterate the string like this, character-by-character. If this worked, you'd just get a print-out for every character anyway. You can just use `in` and provide `'re'` as a substring to get over the issue of checking the next character in the case that `'r'` is found.

```
inp = input("Your Oreo set: ").lower() # don't call your variable "input"
if 'o' in inp or 're' in inp:
    res = "hi, the oreo is being made..."
else:
    res = "hi, this is not an oreo pattern. you can only enter either \'o\' or \'re\' to make one."
```

Comment: @randomkat2035 the iterator is pointless here because you already have the full string in memory; there's nothing to be gained by yielding characters one-by-one (strings are sequences, so that's implicitly what it's going to do)